# Matching Row Height Between UITableviews

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uikit

My application is to display employee schedules at a store.

My design is that on the left side I have a tableview with employee names in each cell, on the right side I have a header with store operation times and below that a colored bar that extends from an employee's start time to their end time.

[image: UI]

The right side of the table must scroll horizontally to so that the user can scroll and see the schedule for any part of the day. I accomplished this effect by putting the times header and the right side table into a scrollview.

In the heightForRowAt function I have

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if tableView.accessibilityIdentifier == "SecondaryTable" {
        var height = tblView.rowHeight
        if let nameCell = tblView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            height = nameCell.frame.height
        } else {
            height = tblView.rowHeight
        }
        return height
    }
    else {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

Which for the name table returns `UITableView.automaticDimension` and for the hours table (accessibility identifier "SecondaryTable") should return the height for the corresponding cell on the name table to make sure they line up properly.

The issue is for some reason `heightForRowAt` is being called for the schedule table when the name table has not loaded the corresponding cell and so it returns `tblView.rowHeight` which is not the correct height. You can see this in the second to last row in the above image. I verified this by checking what indexPath the schedule table was loading and that the index was not in the list of visible cells for the name table.

The only time these tables are being reloaded is in the `viewWillAppear` right now:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tblView.reloadData()
        self.secondTblView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This is only affecting the last row in the table when initially loaded but when the name table does load in the cell doesn't line up with the schedule. It looks like this corrects itself later on but doesn't reload the cell because the information in the cell doesn't change to fill the cell but the next cell starts at the correct spot and the separator lines line up properly.

In case it helps, here is my cellForRow:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "scheduleCell") as? ScheduleCell ?? ScheduleCell()
    let cellSchedule = schedule[indexPath.row]
    if tableView.accessibilityIdentifier == "SecondaryTable" {
        let coloredLabel = UILabel()
        coloredLabel.text = "    " + cellSchedule.role
        coloredLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.darker(by: 35)
        coloredLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        timesHeader.layoutSubviews()
        var drawStartOnHalfHour = false
        var drawEndOnHalfHour = false
        var clockFormat = ClockFormat.TwentyFourHour
        for hour in self.timesHeader.arrangedSubviews{
            let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            let x = hour.center.x
            switch indexPath.row % 2 {
            case 0:
                lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
                break
            default:
                lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                break
            }

            lineLayer.lineWidth = 2
            let path = CGMutablePath()
            if let header = hour as? UILabel, header.text != nil {
                lineLayer.lineDashPattern = [1,5]
                path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: x, y: 5),
                                        CGPoint(x: x, y: cell.contentView.frame.maxY - 5)])
            } else {
                path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: x, y: cell.contentView.frame.maxY/2 - 2),
                                        CGPoint(x: x, y: cell.contentView.frame.maxY/2 + 2)])
            }
            lineLayer.path = path
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.contentView.layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
            }
            if let header = hour as? UILabel {
                if header.text != nil {
                    var afterNoon = false
                    //On the hour logic

                    var formatCheck = ""
                    if header.text!.split(separator: ":").count == 1 {
                        clockFormat = .TwelveHour
                        formatCheck = String(describing: header.text!.split(separator: " ")[1] )
                    }
                    var headerTime = 0
                    if clockFormat == .TwentyFourHour {
                        headerTime = Int(String(describing: header.text!.split(separator: ":")[0])) ?? 0
                    } else {
                        headerTime = Int(String(describing: header.text!.split(separator: " ")[0])) ?? 0
                    }
                    var UTCCalendar = Calendar.current
                    UTCCalendar.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
                    var t = UTCCalendar.component(.hour, from: cellSchedule.StartTime)
                    if clockFormat == .TwelveHour && t >= 12{
                        if t > 12 {
                            t = t-12
                        }
                        afterNoon = true
                    }
                    if headerTime == t {
                        let m = UTCCalendar.component(.minute, from: cellSchedule.StartTime)
                        if clockFormat == .TwentyFourHour || ((afterNoon && formatCheck.contains("p")) || (!afterNoon && formatCheck.contains("a")))   {
                            if m == 0 {
                                //Logic for start times on the hour
                                coloredLabel.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: cell.contentView.frame.maxY/4,
                                                            width: 5, height: cell.contentView.frame.maxY/2)
                            } else {
                                //Logic for handling start times on half-hour
                                drawStartOnHalfHour = true

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    var e = UTCCalendar.component(.hour, from: cellSchedule.EndTime)
                    if clockFormat == .TwelveHour && e >= 12{
                        if e > 12 {
                            e = e - 12
                        }
                        afterNoon = true
                    }
                    if headerTime == e {
                        let m = UTCCalendar.component(.minute, from: cellSchedule.EndTime)
                        if clockFormat == .TwentyFourHour || ((afterNoon && formatCheck.contains("p")) || (!afterNoon && formatCheck.contains("a")))   {
                            if m == 0 {
                                //Logic for end time on the hour
                                let width = x - coloredLabel.frame.minX
                                coloredLabel.frame = CGRect(x: coloredLabel.frame.minX,
                                                            y: coloredLabel.frame.minY,
                                                            width: width, height: coloredLabel.frame.height)
                            } else {
                                //Logic for end time on the half-hour
                                drawEndOnHalfHour = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    //Half-hour logic
                    if drawStartOnHalfHour {
                        drawStartOnHalfHour = false
                        coloredLabel.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: cell.contentView.frame.maxY/4,
                                                    width: 5, height: cell.contentView.frame.maxY/2)
                    } else if drawEndOnHalfHour {
                        drawEndOnHalfHour = false
                        let width = x - coloredLabel.frame.minX
                        coloredLabel.frame = CGRect(x: coloredLabel.frame.minX,
                                                    y: coloredLabel.frame.minY,
                                                    width: width, height: coloredLabel.frame.height)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.contentView.addSubview(coloredLabel)
        }
        switch indexPath.row % 2 {
        case 0:
            let backGround = CALayer()
            backGround.frame = cell.contentView.frame
            backGround.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            cell.contentView.layer.addSublayer(backGround)
            break
        default:
            let backGround = CALayer()
            backGround.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                      y: 0,
                                      width: self.timesHeader.frame.width,
                                      height: cell.contentView.frame.height)
            backGround.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            cell.contentView.layer.addSublayer(backGround)
            break
        }
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
        let firstName = String(describing: cellSchedule.FirstName!.prefix(35))
        let lastName = String(describing: cellSchedule.LastName!.prefix(35))
        cell.textLabel?.text = firstName.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: " ")) + "\n" + lastName.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: " "))
        cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
        switch indexPath.row % 2 {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            break
        default:
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            break
        }

    }

    return cell
}
```

Any idea on a clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: A table view is a scroll view. No need to put a table view in another scroll view.

Comment: Holy smokes. Trying to equate the frames for separate tableviews must be a pain. Can't you create a custom tableviewcell that implements all the logic for each row so you don't have sync problems? Have an external data structure consolidate all the tableview information into one tableview.

Comment: @rmaddy the scrollview is to enable horizontal scrolling, tableviews only support vertical scrolling to my knowledge, please correct me if I am wrong as that would be much easier.

Comment: @Mocha I could probably put a scrollview in each cell to manage the horizontal scrolling at that level, but then I would need to make sure each cell is scrolled to the same offset and that the header lines up which sound like more hasel to me.